# Fab dial stops working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Fab dial stops working when placed in the container which has its visibility dynamically changed from hidden to visible.

The example is dirty but shows the problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqNwZZ

To eliminate the problem just remove:

```
ng-hide="demo.hide"
```

or change js line:

```
this.hide=true;
```

to

```
this.hide=false;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug report 
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7287#event-567461554
and it appears that this is known problem 
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6789

Having container with ng-cloak and using ng-hide on element inside it causes this behavior in fab speedDial.
Since I don't have time now to wait for the resolution I used menu instead.
Check above tickets to see the status of this bug.